# Send lots of data from Android

Tags: android, mobile, server

I have an application in Android, it sends several data in short time. Aprox. 2500 request.

This process is very time-consuming.

What advice can you give me to improve the time?

Thanks

Comment: Try to implement AsyncTask concept during api call.

Comment: Also, you may need to do this whole thing in a Service class in case the data you are sending is absolutely necessary. By the way, what do you mean by short time? A minute or 10, anything below that, then you may need to check your design because prolonged use means more battery usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple **Thread** to send data to the server in the background.

If you are updating UI component after the execution use `AsyncTask`. But you have to run AsyncTask parallelly. You can do that by `AsyncTaskCompat.executeParallel(Your AsyncTask);`

If you wish to send data even your app closed. You can use **service**.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). It handles a lot of threading issues you might be struggling with.

Here's an example from their website.

You'd create an interface for the API you're looking to receive:

```
public interface GitHubService {
   @GET("users/{user}/repos")
  Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

You build a retrofit class

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
    .build();

GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
```

And finally you get a call object:

```
Call<List<Repo>> repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
```

Consuming the call object requires enqueueing a Callback. Here's an example using a different Retrofit service (`TaskService` in this case):

```
TaskService taskService = ServiceGenerator.createService(TaskService.class);  
Call<List<Task>> call = taskService.getTasks();  
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Task>>() {  
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Task>> call, Response<List<Task>> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            // tasks available
        } else {
            // error response, no access to resource?
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Task>> call, Throwable t) {
        // something went completely south (like no internet connection)
        Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

[Source](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests)